# Split bitmap into pieces and save

Tags: c#

I load image from disc:

```
var img = Image.FromFile("foo");
var bmp = new Bitmap(img);
```

I wrote method to split image into pieces:

```
public static IEnumerable<Bitmap> VerticalSplit(this Bitmap src, int pixels)
{
    var bmps = new List<Bitmap>();

    for (int i = 0; i < src.Width; i+=pixels)
    {
        var dst = new Bitmap(pixels, src.Height);
        using (var grD = Graphics.FromImage(dst))
        {
            grD.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(i, 0, pixels, src.Height), new Rectangle(0,0,pixels,src.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            bmps.Add(dst);
        }
    }

    return bmps;
}
```

And this is the usage:

```
var parts = bmp.VerticalSplit(10);

for (int i = 0; i < parts.Count(); i++)
{
    parts[i].Save(@"output/" + i + ".jpg");
}
```

The problem is that every image except 1 is blank. Why does that happen?

Answer (score 2):

See [DrawImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Graphics_DrawImage_System_Drawing_Image_System_Drawing_Rectangle_System_Drawing_Rectangle_System_Drawing_GraphicsUnit_), which has a signature of:

> public void DrawImage (System.Drawing.Image image,
>   System.Drawing.Rectangle destRect, System.Drawing.Rectangle srcRect,
>   System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit srcUnit);

Note that the second parameter is "destRect", and the third parameter is "srcRect".  Your code has the destination and source rectangles **BACKWARDS**.

Change:

```
grD.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(i, 0, pixels, src.Height), new Rectangle(0,0,pixels,src.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

To:

```
grD.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(0,0,pixels,src.Height), new Rectangle(i, 0, pixels, src.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```